# Looping calculations

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to calculate change in habitat cover from over time, starting with `T0` and based on disturbance occurrence (`Disturbance_freq`) and recovery (`Recovery_rate`) in R. I need to loop this calculations for each `Region` based on `Total_Disturbance` (which is different for each region).

My Data is setup as such:

```
Region  Distur_rate Tot_dist  Dist_freq   Impact    Recovery_Rate   T0          T1
0       0.29        29        3.45        20        0.47            0.59        ?
1       0.17        17        5.88        20        0.47            0.59        ?
2       0.4         40        2.5         20        0.47            0.59        ?
```

I am trying to calculate:

```
T1 = (((T0 + Recovery_Rate x Dist_freq) - (20 x (T0 + Recovery_Rate x Dist_freq)/100)) 
T2 = (((T1 + Recovery_Rate x Dist_freq) - (20 x (T1 + Recovery_Rate x Dist_freq)/100))
```

etc...

To do so I coded the following  but there must be a more efficient way to do this:

```
Data <-cbind(Data, (Data$T0 + Data$Recovery_rate * Data$Disturbance_freq)- Data$Impact * 
                     (Data$T0+Data$Recovery_rate * Data$Disturbance_freq)/100)

Data <-cbind(Data, (Data$T1 + Data$Recovery_rate * Data$Disturbance_freq)-Data$Impact * 
                    (Data$T1+Data$Recovery_rate * Data$Disturbance_freq)/100)
```

Comment: I think it is best to post a small example that people can work with along with workable input data and expected output.

Comment: Please edit your post with a sample dataset (preferably the result of `dput( ... )`), and show what you want your results to look like, i.e. offer a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets there do not seem to be correct so you will need to look at them. But this is a case for `apply`. Call your table there `data`

```
data$T1 <- apply(data,1,function(x) {
    (((x[7] + x[6]) * x[4]) - (x[5] * (x[7] + x[6]) * x[4])/100)
    })
data$T2 <- apply(data,1,function(x) {
    (((x[8] + x[6]) * x[4]) - (x[5] * (x[8] + x[6]) * x[4])/100)
    })
```